# p:remoteCommand not executing / not called from javascript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

After calling the javascript function by clicking on logout `p:remotecommand` is not executing.

This is my XHTML code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function logoutAccount() {
    debugger;
    var txt = "eeeeeeeeeeeeeee";
    command([{name:'param',value:txt}]); //This is important
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="logoutAccount()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>   
<p:remoteCommand name="command" action="#{MyiaTaskBean.method}" />
```

This is my code in Java bean:

```java
public void method() {
    String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");
    System.out.print("value is::::::::::::::::::::::"+value);
}
```

I tried to change action by action listener but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`p:remoteCommand` needs to be inside form.

Below code works in my environmet (you haven't said what JSF/PF version you're using):

```
<script>
function logoutAccount() {
    console.log('logoutAccount fired!');
    var txt = 'some text';
    command([{name:'param',value:txt}]);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="logoutAccount()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="command" action="#{testBean.method}" />
</h:form>
```

With your java code the result is:

> value is::::::::::::::::::::::some text